# Creating new SQLAlchemy project with possible future migration to Django in mind

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

I want to create a database with SQLAlchemy ORM. At this moment, no web server is needed, so this solution is ideal. However, it is likely, that in future, we will want to add some web server functionality (using Django).

Are there any recommendations that I should do (when creating SQLAlchemy project) so that the possible migration to Django will be as easy as possible? (for example some naming conventions, using of multi column primary keys, and so on)

I know that we can use Django with existing database, but my question is rather what are the steps I can do at the start of SQLAlchemy project to make the future transition easiest it can be.

Comment: If you're going with Django, then you probably want to use the Django ORM to start with.  You can create management tasks to just directly use the Django ORM, without a website piece.

Comment: @RossRogers Yes, I know, but SQLAlchemy ORM is much better, so for start, I want to use SQLAlchemy, and switch to Django ORM only if necessary.

Comment: :-D  I very much disagree.  I find Django ORM to be fantastic.  Anyways, good luck!